# Retrieve feed from facebook - sdk 4.0

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I've been trying to retrieve someone's facebook feed using both php and javascript but nothing has worked so far. According to what I've tried, a session is needed to retrieve an access token and therefore be able to see someone else's publicly feed - developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#usertokens

If we try the following url: **graph.facebook.com/PAGE-ID/feed** it returns an error saying that An access token is required to request this resource.

Below's my **javascript attempt**, based on the facebook sdk documentation:
http://pastebin.com/2KkU0iyF

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
       FB.init
            ({
                appId   : 'APP-ID',
                status  : true, // check login status
                cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                xfbml   : true, // parse XFBML
                version: 'v2.2'
            });
            FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function()
            {
                window.location.reload();
            });

      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
          if (response.status === 'connected') {
            console.log('Logged in.');
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

           if(typeof facebookInit !== 'undefined')
                  facebookInit();
          }
          else {
            FB.login(function (response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                  // some code here

                } else {
                  alert("Login attempt failed!");
                }
              } //, { scope: 'read_stream' } // do I need to use scope here?
            );;
           }
        });
    };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


function facebookInit() {

    FB.api('/PAGE-ID/feed', function(response) {
       console.log(response); // the returned array is empty
});


}
```

> Thing is, the **/PAGE-ID/feed** is returning an empty array. I've tried to ask for something like **/me** and it prints basic information in the console, like name, id, username and so on.
>
> Console output:
>
> **Objectdata: Array[0]
>   __proto__: Object**
>
> I believe I'm missing something simple like permissions or so (I tried to use scope in the login phase). However, according to the Graph API documentation (developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post/),
>   any valid access token should work if the post is public.

**PHP attempt:** http://pastebin.com/4wCBqSTu

```
session_start();

define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))));
require (__ROOT__.'/resources/facebook-php-sdk-v4-4.0-dev/autoload.php');

// added in v4.0.5
use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;

// added in v4.0.0
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\GraphUser;

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('APP-ID','APP-SECRET');

// get app access_token
$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();

// make request to Facebook                        
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/PAGE-ID/feed' ); // /PAGE-ID only would retrieve the basic info, like username
$response = $request->execute();
// get response as array


$content = $response->getGraphObject();
print_r($content);
// output html
?>
```

> First things first. Do I really need to ask for login here? I only want to read the public posts. Isn't app-id and app-secret enough to generate the session?
>   According to the documentation, the **/feed** returns an array of **post** objects.
>
> However, when I use **/PAGE-ID/feed** the return is an empty array: **[backingData:protected] => Array ( )**
>
> If I use **/PAGE-ID** only, it prints the basic information, such as username, name, etc..

Any suggestions?

**Edit**
Working examples:

pastebin.com/8WzmzxX0

pastebin.com/wKcfB8vj

Thanks

Comment: please post your code here.

Comment: I've just added it to the thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even for public posts, you MUST use a User Token for the specific User, and you need to authorize him with the `read_stream` permission.

That being said, you may want to read this:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2

That is for User profiles. If you want to retrieve a Page feed, you can even use an App Token without authorization, unless the Page is restricted (country, age) - in that case you need to use a User Token or Page Token. More information about Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: I've tried to authorize with read_stream permission (javascript sample) but it didn't work. The User Token is retrieved with the login, right?

Thanks

Comment: yes, but you usually don´t need to worry about tokens, the sdk handles the tokens internally. what means "it didn´t work"?

Comment: btw, you are using FB.login in a wrong way. check out this tutorial: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: I've tried the login the way you suggested and that part is working. Using read_stream, as you also suggested, I have access to the news feed, but how can I use that information? The response from /me/feed just prints [object Object]

Comment: that is a whole different story, it is a json object. use the chrome dev tools for debuggint, they list json objects.

Comment: If I use response.data i get a bunch of [object Object]. I believe it's a matter of calling the right stuff now

Comment: yes, you need to learn how to deal with json data. as i said, the chrome dev tools show json data, not just object.

Comment: Just found that someone's feed is different than a page's feed, hence having trouble with the wall posts I was looking for in the json data. Thanks for the help!

Comment: ok, i will add some more information about page feeds to my answer too

Comment: Do you recommend using an App Token instead for page's feed then? I mean, it's enough if the feed has no restrictions as you explained.